# Executing bash commands in python error

Tags: python, bash, cygwin, subprocess

I am trying to write a python script to test a 4 digit pincode with brute forcing(and a password) when connecting to local host. The command that needs to be run is:

`echo password pincode | nc localhost 30002 >> /tmp/joesPin/pinNumber`

(writes response to a new file).

This worked when written as a bash script, but I am struggling with the subprocess module in Python.

```
import subprocess

password = "UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ"

for i in range(10000):

    pincode = str('{0:04}'.format(i)) #changes 4 to 0004
    subprocess.call('echo', password, pincode,'|','nc localhost 30002 >> /tmp/joesPin/' + pincode,shell=True)
```

I want it to call:

```
echo UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0001 | nc localhost 30002 >> /tmp/joesPin/0001
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to pipe the output of a command in Python.

Option 1: You can set the `stdout` argument of the `subprocess.call` command and write the output somewhere.

Option 2: You can use `subprocess.PIPE` in the `Popen`call and save the output to use with another command.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', password, pincode], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0] # now contains the output of running "proc"

file = '/tmp/joesPin/pinNumber'
with open(file, 'a+') as out:
    subprocess.call(['nc localhost 30002'], stdout=out, shell=True)
```

Setting the `stdout` field in `subprocess.call` writes the output of the subprocess to the file descriptor given in `stdout`.

To use the output of the 1st process as the stdin input of the 2nd process:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', password, pincode], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0] # now contains the output of running "proc"

file = '/tmp/joesPin/pinNumber'
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['nc localhost 30002'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
proc2.stdin.write(output)
result = proc2.communicate()[0]

# now you can write the output to the file:
with open (file, 'a+') as outfile:
    outfile.write(result)
```